# onclick event google apps script

Tags: forms, button, google-apps-script

my onclick event for a button never gets called:

Here is the hello.html (html script)

```
<html>
Hello World!!

  <form id="myForm">

   <input type="button" onclick='google.script.run.processForm(this.parentNode)'
 value='Submit!' name="submit">
  </form>
</html>
```

and here is Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('hello').evaluate();
}

function processForm(myForm) {
  logtoerrorsheet("Hello Button");  
}


function logtoerrorsheet(mystring){
  //return;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheetID').getSheets()[0];
  var range = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 2);
  var values = [[new Date(), mystring]]; 
  range.setValues(values); 
}
```

If I run processForm from the editor, I see it logs the call to my spreadsheet. But when I run the app and see the Hello World with the submit button underneath it, clicking the button does nothing.

Comment: There's a bug with this right now. We're addressing it ASAP. You can follow along here: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1660

Comment: thanks .. (gluing my hair back in)